# Trouble with Jquery widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-widgets

I have a widget like this

```
$.widget("ui.myWidget", {
    //default options
    options: {
        myOptions: "test"
    },
    _create: function () {
        this.self = $(this.element[0]);
        this.self.find("thead th").click(function () {
            this.self._headerClick(); //how do I do this!!!
        });
        this.self._somethingElse();
    },
    _headerClick: function (){
    },
    _somethingElse: function (){
    },
.
.
.
```

The line `this.self._headerClick();` throws an error. This is because in that context `this` is the `th` element that was clicked. How do I get a reference to the _headerClick function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store the scope of desired `this` within a variable.

```
$.widget("ui.myWidget", {
    //default options
    options: {
        myOptions: "test"
    },
    _create: function () {
        var that = this; // that will be accessible to .click(...
        this.self = $(this.element[0]);
        this.self.find("thead th").click(function () {
            that._headerClick(); //how do I do this!!!
        });
        this.self._somethingElse();
    },
    _headerClick: function (){
    },
    _somethingElse: function (){
    },
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to do `that._somethingElse();`?  I don't think `this.self._somethingElse();` will fire.

Comment: yes, I just realized that before, I simplified the example so you wouldn't get a headache reading through unessential code, and i screwed that up.

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but maybe something like this:

```
_create: function () {
    var self = this,
        $elem = $(self.element[0]);

    $elem.find("thead th").click(function() {
        self._headerClick();
    });

    self._somethingElse();
},
```